# jQuery Mobile - Header not rendering on second page

Tags: jquery, mobile, header, rendering

Can please someone put me out of my misery and tell me why this doesn't work?

I have a simple 2 page test site - each page has a header and a link to the other page - so you can just click from one to the next and back etc.

Everything looks fine when the site loads - page 1 shows with a header. Clicking the button to page 2 the page loads but the header is not rendered as with page 1.

I didn't think I had to do anything special for such a simple test but can't work out what's wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Mobile Test</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="pg_1">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="close" href="#pg_2">Goto Page 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="pg_2">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" data-rel="close" href="#pg_1">Goto Page 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried with jQuery 1.7 as well but the same result.

I must be doing something idiotic but just can't see it. Any help greatly aprreciated.

Regards
Nymor

edit: can't add images as I'm a newbie but page 1 and page 2 as they look for me can be seen at

```
http://i104.photobucket.com/albums/m186/Nymor/misc/jqm_t1-1.png
http://i104.photobucket.com/albums/m186/Nymor/misc/jqm_t1-2.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `data-rel="close"` from links.

Here is the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Mobile Test</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id="pg_1" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p><a data-role="button" href="#pg_2">Goto Page 2</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="pg_2" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p><a data-role="button" href="#pg_1">Goto Page 1</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks phemios - don't know how that got in there.

Comment: You can check all available attributes [in doc's data attribute reference](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/data-attributes.html)